# Picture field does not contain dictionary

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api, dictionary

I am trying to prepare for one of the changes in the roadmap (http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/)

> "Picture connection/field may return a dictionary We will start
>   returning a dictionary containing the fields url, height, width, and
>   is_silhouette when accessing the /picture connection for an object and
>   specifying a callback property, a redirect=false parameter, or getting
>   the picture field as part of a larger JSON response."

I have enabled the migration in my app settings. So far I have not been able to get a response that contains a dictionary in the picture field. I have tested "me/home" which should qualify as a larger JSON response, and I have also tested using the callback and redirect parameters.

Any more ideas or sample calls that return a dictionary in the picture field?

Answer (score 0):

An example using picture connection of a public page profile with "redirect=false" returns dictionary for page.  The image used for the page i would imagine is not large enough to have multiple sizes, but the dictionary does return "is_silhouette": false.

see: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=anotherfeed%2Fpicture%3Fredirect%3Dfalse